# Combinatorics question from an exam in 2015

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A committee of $11$ people is to be formed from $8$ males and $5$ females. If $m$ is the number of ways the committee is formed with at least $6$ males, and $n$ is the number of ways the committee is formed with at least $3$ females, then what are $m$ and $n$?

---

The answer is

> $$m = n = 78$$

It can be solved by classical combination tactics but I wanted to solve it using generating functions and I wrote them like that:

\begin{align*}
m&=(x^6+x^7+x^8)(1+x+\dots+x^5)\\[5pt]
n&=(1+x+\dots+x^8)(x^3+x^4+x^5)\\[5pt]
\end{align*}

However, for $m$ and $n$, the coefficient is $3$. Where did I make mistake? Why didn't generating functions give correct answer?

Comment: Rethink your coefficients, there is more than 1 way to more a committee of 1 females out of 5 and similarly for the others.

Comment: This generating function will not be able to select $6$ out of $8$ men for example!

Comment: @MathLover then what is right form ?

Comment: @Mo145 i get my coefficients calculated by wolfram alpha

Comment: The number $3$ you’ve calculated assumes that the men are indistinguishable and the women are indistinguishable. The correct. product is $$\left(\binom86 x^6+\binom87x^7+\binom 88x^8\right)(1+x)^5,$$ with the coefficient of $x^{11}$ being $m.$

Comment: Note that $$m=(x^6+x^7+x^8)(1+x+\dots+x^5)$$ is an abuse of notations. This kind of relationship can sometimes be written: $$m=\left[x^{11}\right]\left(x^6+x^7+x^8\right)\left(1+x+\dots+x^5\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First notice that *any* committee of 11 must include at least 6 men, since it can only include at most 5 women. Similarly, *any* committee of 11 must include at least 3 women, since it can only include at most 8 men. So the question is actually asking how many different ways can we choose 11 people from 13 people. In generating function terms, this is the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{13}$.

Comment: Nice simplification of the issue (+1)